# Filtration and martingale property in practice

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales, random-walk

I am trying to setup a simple exercise to understand how a stochastic process is built, since I am following a course that totally lacks any practical example. I wanted to build a martingale from scratch, starting from the simplest example of random walk:

> 1. sample space: $\Omega = \{\omega\in(0,1]\}$
> 2. random process as a family of random variables $(X_i)_{i=0}^\infty$
> 3. $X_0=0$
> 4. $X_1=-1$ if $\omega \leq 0.5$, $1$ otherwise
> 5. $X_2=-2$ if $\omega\leq 0.25$, $0$ if $0.25<\omega\leq0.75$, 2 otherwise
> 6. $X_{i>2}$ alike
> 7. a filtration $(\mathcal F_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ is built on $\mathcal F=\sigma(\Omega)$: $\mathcal F_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, $\mathcal F_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega,(0,0.5],(0.5,1]\}$, $\mathcal F_2=\{\emptyset,\Omega,(0,0.25],(0.25,0.75],(0.75,1],(0,0.75],(0.25,1],(0,0.25]\sqcup(0.75,1]\}$. Note that every $\mathcal F_i$ contains $2^i$ elements.

Now I want to check if the process is a martingale, that should be. So I check if

$$X_1\stackrel{?}{=}\mathbb E[X_2|\mathcal F_1]=
\begin{cases}
?&\text{ on }\emptyset\\
0&\text{ on }\Omega\\
-2\cdot0.25+0\cdot0.25&\text{ on }(0,0.5]\\
0\cdot0.25+2\cdot0.25&\text{ on }(0.5,0.1]
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
?&\text{ on }\emptyset\\
0&\text{ on }\Omega\\
-0.5&\text{ on }(0,0.5]\\
0.5&\text{ on }(0.5,0.1]
\end{cases}.$$

In the way I am computing the conditional expectation, clearly it does not look like a martingale. Would you please let me know where I am misunderstanding things?

Plus, would you please suggest me a book or notes on stochastic processes with such examples, where I can get a *practical* understanding of what I am doing?

Comment: When conditioned on $(0,0.5]$, don't you need to use the conditional probabilities and evaluate $E[X_2 \mid F_1] = -2 \times 0.5 + 0 \times 0.5 = -1$?  If so, then you also need to flip the signs (you had $X_1 = 1$ in this case) but after that you'd have $E[X_2 \mid F_1] = X_1$.

Comment: Thank you @antkam, I badly wrote, and now corrected, $X_1$. But, why should I use the conditional probabilities? By the definition of a conditional expectation, I should consider the indicator function of the set I am conditioning over, for every set of the filtration I am conditioning over?

Comment: Sorry, I should have realized you're asking a _theory_ question, for which I'm out of my depth.  My _intuitive understanding_ is that the requirement "$X_1 = E[X_2 \mid F_1]$" means something like for every event $E \in F_1$, we have $X_1(E) = E[X_2 \mid E]$, where I wrote $X_1(E)$ because the value of $X_1$ is determined by $E$.  But hopefully, someone better grounded in the theoretical machinery can give you a more solid answer.